# Mybatis return -1 when insert and update query execute

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, sybase

If Insert or update query execute successfully, mybatis return value is -1.
I understand that if the query is successful, if 1 fails, 0 should be returned.
but it's not working. My Database is Sybase. And I don't use Batch Statement
Does anyone happen to know about this issue?

Comment: Please show us the exact steps to reproduce the problem. The best way is to create a small demo project and share it on your GitHub repo. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some templates and examples.